# Sending POST data using JQUERY UI to Django

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-templates

I'm following the example provided in the JQUERY UI [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) to create a dialog form. I have `method=POST` and `action= "{% url 'example:new_article' %}"` in the form, so I recon that the form should be submitted when I click on the "Add Article' button. Am I missing something? I know that with AJAX I would do something along the lines of 
`$.ajax({url: new_article`}
How can I do that this with JQuery and without AJAX? My understanding is that I don't need AJAX because it's a pop-up form. I don't want the form window to stay up once the user creates an article. I want to save and for the window to close.

I've been looking around, but can't find an example that shows the correct way of sending POST data to Django views.

js

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var dialog, form,
    exampleName = $( "#exampleName" ),
    articleTitle = $( "#articleTitle" ),
    articleLink = $( "#articleLink" ),
    allFields = $( [] ).add( exampleName ).add( articleTitle ).add( articleLink ),
    tips = $( ".validateTips" );


    function updateTips( t ) {
        tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Fields cannot be empty or be longer than 255 characters");
        return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    }


    function addArticle() {
    var valid = true;
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

    valid = valid && checkLength( exampleName, "exampleName", 1, 100 );
    valid = valid && checkLength( articleTitle, "articleTitle", 1, 250 );
    valid = valid && checkLength( articleLink, "articleLink", 1, 250 );

    if ( valid ) {
        console.log("made it through validation"
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
    return valid;
    }

    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add Article": addArticle,
        Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addArticle();
    });

    $( "#create-article" ).button().on( "click", function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
    } );
</script>
```

index.html

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Article">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
     <form action= "{% url 'example:new_article' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
        <label for="exampleName">Example</label>
        <input type="text" name="exampleName" id="exampleName" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="articleTitle">Article Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="articleTitle" id="articleTitle" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="articleLink">Article Link</label>
        <input type="articleLink" name="articleLink" id="articleLink" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.main, name= "main"),
  path('new_article',views.new_article, name="new_article"),
  ]
```

views.py

```
def new_article(request):
    print("made it to views")
    print(request.POST)
    return render (request, 'example/index.html')
```

I suspect that the issue is around:

```
    if ( valid ) {
    console.log("made it through validation"
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
}
return valid;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. `$.ajax()` *is* jQuery.

Comment: So, I need to use AJAX to send the POST data?

Comment: I thought that since it’s a pop-up it didn’t need AJAX

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying. If you don't want to use Ajax, don't use Ajax; if you do, you can do it via the jQuery `$.ajax` call.

Comment: My apologies if my question was not clear. I modified it and I hope it is more useful and clear now. I do not want to use AJAX. My understanding is that I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did need AJAX. I changed the following:

**html**

From:

```
<form action= "{% url 'example:new_article' %}" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form id="new_form">
```

**script**

From:

```
if ( valid ) {
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
}
return valid;
}
```

To:

`if ( valid ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'new_article',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#new_form').serialize()
                                        })
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
    return valid;
    }`